# How to send an Object with jQuery's .post() function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, object, post

```
var itemsObj = new Object();
itemsObj.data = "Something";
$.post("somewhere.php", itemsObj, function(data) {}, "html");
```

Normally, as stated in the API, I'd use `{ data: "something" }` where `itemsObj` is, but since my object is dynamic and requires a for-loop, I didn't want to get too 'dirty' with a for loop within the `data: ...` part...

Anyways, the code I wrote above doesn't work. I think maybe I should've apply the `JSON.stringify()` function on it, correct if I'm wrong?

Comment: What does the server want? A JSON-string? URL-encoded key-value pairs?

Comment: Can you clarify 'doesnt work'? What do you see in the network requests section of your dev tools? How about on your backend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add data to itemsObj like this...

```
var itemsObj = {};

itemsObj['Firstdata'] = "Something";
itemsObj['Seconddata'] = "Something else";
```

etc... You can use looping to do that...

Then post using `$.post("somewhere.php", itemsObj, function(data) {}, "html");` and it should work...

Comment: Thanks. Seems like `obj.['something']` doesn't work so I had to change it to `obj['data']`, then I tried sending the `object` to the other page, but that didn't work either. Normally I'd send it as `{ data: "something" }` and access it like that `$_POST['data']`, what's different now?

Comment: Thanks. How'd I send/receive the object though? I tried looking at @Engineer's answer, look's reliable thought I do I access `data` for example? :P

Comment: @xTCx the above thing will do exactly that when you post itemsObj above it will post something like `{"Firstdata":"Something","Seconddata":"Something else"}` which is a valid JSON object and you can access it via `$_POST["Firstdata"]`

Comment: @xTCx you send using `$.post("somewhere.php",itemsObj, function(data){},"html");` :)

Comment: ah! okay yeah there was actually a typo in my code ;) Thank you!! :D

Comment: @xTCx No problem mine was a bigger typo thanks for pointing it out :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use JSON:

```
$.post("somewhere.php", "param="+JSON.stringify(itemsObj), function(data) {}, "html");
```

Then in server side:

```
$obj = json_decode($_POST["param"]);
```

Comment: You're assuming that he's using PHP for his backend.

Comment: Yes, I am assuming that, look at the question.There is  `"somewhere.php"` mentioned as post's URL.

Comment: @MisterJack I am assuming also, that your downvote is irrelevant.

Comment: +1 @Engineer : Dont worry about downvoting,Anonymous downvoting has became like a virus in SO

Comment: @user1042031 It is not anonymous in this case:)